# How do I install SCID Chess on a Mac?

Tags: scid, macos

I tried to download SCID for Mac and when I downloaded the latest version, I got a scid-src.zip. When I extracted this, I get a bunch of folders and source files. How do I launch this application? I see no launcher file.

Thank you,
Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think SCID supports Mac OSX officially. The files you have are raw sources, which you'll need to compile with TCL. Why not try a newer (and better) SCID alternative?

Download SCID vs PC

http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be opened anymore in macOS Catalina: it says developer cannot be verified :/ If you have any suggestions for other apps or workarounds it'd be much appreciated. I'm just looking for a chess app for mac where I can have a board editor and highlighting features (drawing arrows, and coloring squares to highlights, etc). Many thanks in advance

Comment: @user929304 "developer cannot be verified" is mac's security configuration preventing you from opening apps that aren't downloaded from the app store or other verified source. You can adjust these settings in order to open non-verified apps. Just google "mac developer cannot be verified".

Answer (score 3):

You probably downloaded the Windows version.
The Mac version can be downloaded here: http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/#toc3
The name (ScidvsMac-4.16-ElCap.dmg) probably means that you need El Capitan (the latest Mac OS X version) to run it.